# python, list and generator concatenation

Tags: python, list, generator

I want to join in a list, a generator and a list. For example at Step 1 , I have an empty list

```
A = []
```

and generator B which gives me the combinations of a list L:

```
B = combinations(list(L[0]), 2),
```

which give me for example `B=[(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]`

I want to have a list `A = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]`

Step 2:

```
A = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]
B = combinations(list(L[1]), 2)= [(2,4),(4,5)]
```

I want now my A to be:

```
A = A + B = [ (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,4),(4,5) ]
```

How is that possible ?

Comment: Have you tried `A + list(B)`?

Comment: `L[0]` is already an iterable if you can pass it as an argument to `list`, which means you can pass it directly to `combinations` as well: `B = combinations(L[0], 2)`.

Comment: If you had tried `A = A + B`, you would have known that this is the output you were looking for.

Comment: `A.extend(combinations(list(L[0]),2))`

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain


A = list(chain(A, B))
```

If you want to modify `A` in place, just use `extend` (whose argument can be any iterable value):

```
A.extend(B)
```

Comment: That seems to work. But how can I check if C = [12, 15] is in A=list(chain(A, B))= [(12,14), (12,15)] ? Because condition (if C is in A) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Because it isn't. `C` is a list, and `A` is a list of *tuples*, not a list of lists. Try `tuple(C) in A`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python `extend()` [method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/extend):

```
A = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]
B = [(2,4),(4,5)]

A.extend(B)
```

Now A has the value `[ (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,4), (4,5) ]`

This also seems to work fine:

```
A = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]
B = [(2,4),(4,5)]

A = A + B
```